# how to resolve invoking bsh method?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to read a CSV file using Beah Shell Assertion . below is my bean shell script

```
       import java.io.BufferedReader;
       import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
       import java.io.FileReader;
       import java.io.IOException;

       String csvFile = 
      "C:/Workspace/JmeterProjects/JMeterOutput_${__time(MM-dd-yyyy)}.csv";
       BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
       String line = "";
       String SEPARATOR = ",";

     try {
         bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));

              int counter = 1;
       while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
          {
               String[] items = line.split(SEPARATOR);
        print("--------------------LOGGING STARTS-----------------------");
   for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
       {        
           log.info(items[i]);
       }   
        print("--------------------LOGGING ENDS-------------------------");
       }

       } 
       catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
       {
                 e.printStackTrace();
      } 
      catch (IOException e) 
      {
                 e.printStackTrace();
      } 
      finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
               try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                    }
               }

        }
```

But i have got the error saying

> ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.BufferedReader; import java.io.FileNotFoundException; import java . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 6, column 22.  Encountered: "W" (87), after : "\"C:\"

I am not sure what could be error behind this

Answer (score 0):

The updated code that you shared is running fine with the exact same conditions including the file path on my windows system. Only file contents are different. Please find below the output. If you are still seeing the original error with the updated code, Please share more information like logs etc.

```
2019-03-29 12:04:34,123 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2019-03-29 12:04:34,137 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: col1
2019-03-29 12:04:34,137 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: col2
2019-03-29 12:04:34,138 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: col3
2019-03-29 12:04:34,138 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: col4
2019-03-29 12:04:34,138 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: col5
2019-03-29 12:04:34,138 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: col6
2019-03-29 12:04:34,138 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: col7
2019-03-29 12:04:34,138 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: col8
2019-03-29 12:04:34,138 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: col9
2019-03-29 12:04:34,138 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: col10
.
.
.
2019-03-29 12:04:34,170 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: val25





<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.0 r1840935">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
              <url>true</url>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
              <idleTime>true</idleTime>
              <connectTime>true</connectTime>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
        <DebugSampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugSampler" testname="Debug Sampler" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
        </DebugSampler>
        <hashTree>
          <BeanShellAssertion guiclass="BeanShellAssertionGui" testclass="BeanShellAssertion" testname="BeanShell Assertion" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="BeanShellAssertion.query">      import java.io.BufferedReader;
       import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
       import java.io.FileReader;
       import java.io.IOException;

       String csvFile = 
      &quot;C:/Workspace/JmeterProjects/JMeterOutput_${__time(MM-dd-yyyy)}.csv&quot;;
       BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
       String line = &quot;&quot;;
       String SEPARATOR = &quot;,&quot;;

     try {
         bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));

              int counter = 1;
       while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
          {
               String[] items = line.split(SEPARATOR);
        print(&quot;--------------------LOGGING STARTS-----------------------&quot;);
   for(int i = 0; i &lt; items.length; i++)
       {        
           log.info(items[i]);
       }   
        print(&quot;--------------------LOGGING ENDS-------------------------&quot;);
       }

       } 
       catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
       {
                 e.printStackTrace();
      } 
      catch (IOException e) 
      {
                 e.printStackTrace();
      } 
      finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
               try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                    }
               }

        }</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="BeanShellAssertion.filename"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="BeanShellAssertion.parameters"></stringProp>
            <boolProp name="BeanShellAssertion.resetInterpreter">false</boolProp>
          </BeanShellAssertion>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Comment: dude , seriously . It was just a copy-pasting issue from my jmeter to SOF  . The issue that you stated are not at all my question , Coming to your question - yes , i have a file which has date populated at the suffix  . Now - can you address the actual question that i asked (if you have solution for it )?

Comment: We can only given our feedback based on the code that you share with us.  We cannot predict the original code. Given that, the original error is a "lexical" error, I can only guess code/whitespace/compilation issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Don't use Beanshell for scripting, since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
2. [Don't inline JMeter Functions into scripts, use code-based equivalents instead](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

Groovy equivalent would be something like:

```
new File('C:\Workspace\JmeterProjects/JMeterOutput_' + new Date().format('MM-dd-yyyy') + '.csv').readLines().each { line ->
    line.split(',').each { entry ->
        log.info(entry)
    }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)